# Не могу запустить компиляцию программы после загрузки из github rep

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github

Скачал из своего github программу, которую делал на другой системе, с помощью архива. Открыл в intellij idea как проект, поместив в папку с остальными проектами. Программа собирается, но не запускается, ниже приложены скрины.

При создание нового конфига, по инструкции из другой темы, не видит main
[image: При создание нового конфига, по инструкции из другой темы, не видит main]

Все SDKs в порядке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, у Вас папка src не выбрана как исходные коды. Правой кнопкой мыши по ней и выберите пункт "Mark directory as" > "Source root"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло